# Get other posts sharing the same meta values

Tags: posts, meta-query

I want to get all posts having the same meta values.

My Post A has 2 meta values: ID 182 and ID 183

I want to have all post having meta 182 or 183, excepting the current one of course.

I have tried:

```
$metaSearch = [
    'relation' => 'OR'
];

// tags are the tags (meta tag_initiative) of current post
if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $metaSearch [] = [
            'key' => 'tag_iniative',
            'value' => $tag->term_id,
            'compare' => '=',
        ];
    }
}
// array(2) { ["relation"]=> string(2) "OR" [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(12) "tag_iniative" ["value"]=> int(182) ["compare"]=> string(1) "=" } }
var_dump($metaSearch);

$initiativesOther = get_posts([
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'initiative',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'exclude' => [get_the_ID()],
    'meta_query' => $metaSearch,
]);
```

This won't bring me any post, but:

```
$initiativesOther = get_posts([
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'initiative',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'exclude' => [get_the_ID()],
    'meta_query' => [
        'key' => 'tag_iniative',
        'value' => 182,
        'compare' => '=',
    ],
]);
```

Will work and shows me an other post. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the meta like this

```
'meta_query' => [
    'key' => 'tag_iniative',
    'value' => [182,183],
    'compare' => 'IN',
]
```